# .htaccess https only for homepage and http for other

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-redirect

I have a site eg: example.com with Lets Encrypt SSL installed. I want to force redirect all url from https to http but at the same time I want the homepage to be force redirect from http to https. Is such thing possible?
Thank you.

My current .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
    RewriteRule .* index.php [F,L]
</IfModule>
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://clix2reach.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Turn HTTPs on for homepage
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Turn HTTP on for everything but homepage
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Change `index.php` depending on file name / extension.